# How can I reset a file handle receiving standard input in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, seek

When I issue a Perl script some standard input, e.g.

```
$ awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' foo.txt | myScript.pl
```

I have a script which contains a bug. It reads the first line of standard input, gets something from that first line, and then only parses lines 2 through n of standard input on subsequent read:

```
open (FH, "< $input") or die $?;
my $firstLine = <FH>; // reads first line

...

while (my $line = <FH>) {
    // reads lines 2 through n
}
close (FH);
```

So I added a `seek` statement to this script to try to reset the file handle to the beginning of the file:

```
use Fcntl qw(:seek);

...

open (FH, "< $input") or die $?;
my $firstLine = <FH>; // reads first line
seek (FH, 0, SEEK_SET) or die "error: could not reset file handle\n"; // should reset file handle

...

while (my $line = <FH>) {
    // reads lines 1 through n (in theory)
}
close (FH);
```

Adding this `seek` statement works for file input, but not for standard input. The script crashes with the error:

```
 error: could not reset file handle
```

How can I correctly read the first line of standard input at the start of the script, reset the file handle and then read all lines 1 through n of the standard input?

I guess I can write a special case for storing and processing the first line before the `while` loop, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution to this problem that allows me to handle both standard input and file input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an easy way:

```
open (FH, "< $input") or die $?;
my $line = <FH>; // reads first line

//do stuff with first line

do {
    //stuff
} while ($line = <FH>);
```

Comment: Of course! I completely forgot about `do-while`. Very elegant, thank you.

Comment: Just remember that next/last don't see the do{} as a block; see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers for the standard workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Drawback of my first approach is that it must load all lines from `FH` into memory before processing the list. This approach, using the open to scalar reference feature (available since 5.8.0) won't have that problem:

```
my $firstline = <FH>;
open(my $f1, '<', \$firstline);

...

while (my $line = <$f1> || <FH>) {
    # process line 1 through n
}
```

---

How about:

```
for my $line ($firstline, <FH>) {
    # process lines 1 through n
}
```

Comment: I like using `while` because I deal with very large files. Using `for` requires, as you've noted, storing all the input data in memory before processing it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reset (or seek(0)) for STDIN.  It isn't a normal file handle as STDIN. Since it isn't actually a file, you would require the STDIN does resettable buffering.

I think you'll need to handle the reading and re-using of line 1 specially.

Comment: The issue isn't that it's STDIN, it's that it isn't a file.  seek will fail on other filehandles that are pipes or other non-seekable types; seek will succeed even on STDIN if it is a file, for example: `seq 9 >foo; perl -we'seek STDIN, 12, 0; print scalar <>' <foo` prints 7, not 1.